# VPS doesn't allow connections, filtered ports?

Tags: windows, networking, firewall, windows-server-2012, vps

I have a Windows Server 2012 VPS, which I'm hosting a game server on. My users needs to connect to the client, through a web-based client. My problem is that, it doesn't seem to be able to connect to my VPS.

It returns this error:

- IOError ioError on connect: Socket Timeout (20000 ms). Possible Firewall.. Port was  30018
- SecurityError in 20028
- SecurityError on connect: Error #2048. Port was 30018
- Connection attempt 3
- Memory usage: 96 MB .
- error_desc=Connection failed to host and ports .

I contacted my VPS provider and they told me this:

> Sir, you have firewall active on your server - port scans show filtered ports. please check in details and disable it.
>
> we do not block anything, even from local network we could see only http responfing from you

I've already turned the VPS' Firewall off:

[image]

I did some googling, on how to disable the Firewall on Windows Server 2012 and they had a picture the same as mine (see image below) but with another Firewall called Domain Firewall. I don't have this one?

[image]

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, I've really searched a lot but I can't seem to find out, why my web client won't connect to the game servers emulator.

> CanYouSeeMe.org:
> Success: I can see your service on [IP] on port (30018)
> Your ISP is not blocking port 30018

**EDIT:**

I found Domain Firewall and turned it off, but my web client is still not able to connect.

Comment: You sure the problem isn't with the web-based client? You shouldn't have to disable your firewall to do what you want.  The two screenshots look exactly the same.

Comment: They're meant to be the same. And yes, I'm able to connect through my VPS, so I'm sure it's a problem with my VPS.

Comment: Its simple.  If you have disabled Windows Firewall then your problem cannot be Windows Firewall your service provider is likely to blame.